# MySQL Performance - 5 Million Rows

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have an **local** DB on **Mamp** for performance testing. My problem table has about **5 Million** rows.

This is the table i`ve ran in to problems with:

```
 1  User_ID     int(11)                                     
 2  Skill_ID    int(11)                                         
 3  Matching    int(11)                                         
 4  Grade       int(11)
```

Index is User_ID and Skill_ID.

This is the query I use:

```
  SELECT User_ID,COUNT(Matching),SUM(Matching)
   FROM Matching
   WHERE Skill_ID = 3 OR Skill_ID 5 OR Skill_ID = 18 ............
   GROUP BY User_ID
   ORDER BY SUM(Matching) DESC
```

The more skills i select in on my testsite the more time consuming my query is.
At the moment it takes ca. **1 second** for the first skill and raises by ca. **0.25s per selected skill**.
So for 5 Skills i already need more than 2 seconds.

I already created indexes and tried many different modification in the my.cnf of MySQL (increase key_buffer_size,enable query_cache,sort_buffer_size......)

WAMP runs on my Mac Book AIR 2012, 4GB RAM,1,8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 Prozessor.

The table is MyISAM. I can't avoid the ORDER BY and the COUNT and SUM function, they are too important for the query.

The table is estimated to grow to more than 50 Million entries.

**EDIT:**
This is the result of the EXPLAIN command

- id            1
- select_type   SIMPLE
- table         Matching
- type    ALL
- possible_keys NULL
- key           NULL
- key_len       NULL
- ref           NULL
- rows          5285936
- Extra         Using where;Using temporary; Using filesort

**How can I improve the performance of my DB ?Do I just need better hardware?
Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT:**
SAME TABLE NOW WITH PARTITIONS

```
Create table Matching2 (User_ID int,Skill_ID int,Matching int,Note int)
Partition by Range (Skill_ID) (
Partition S0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
Partition S1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
Partition S2 VALUES LESS THAN (30),
Partition S3 VALUES LESS THAN (40),
Partition S4 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
Partition S5 VALUES LESS THAN (60),
Partition S6 VALUES LESS THAN (70),
Partition S7 VALUES LESS THAN (80)
);
```

--> no significant performance improvement!

Comment: you should try with `where in` condition

Comment: I did but no significant improvement with "where in"

Comment: you need to show out the table structure, the command `explain` and `desc`

Comment: `index` skill id field

Comment: oh I forgot to say that User_ID and Skill_ID are indexed

Comment: What kind of hard drive are you using? SSD or conventional? If conventional - is this 7200RPM?

Comment: What's the result of the `explain` command?

Comment: Is it necessary that all those fields be full int(11)?  Seems like some could be smaller (e.g. Skill_ID).  Using smaller fields will reduce the table and index sizes resulting in less IO and less memory to hold the indexes.

Comment: Try rewriting the where condition like `Skill_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)`.  MySQL can usually optimize `IN`s better than many `OR`s.  If you don't already have one, try adding a composite index on `(Skill_ID, User_ID)`.  The main problem is that your query isn't using an index and getting it to use an index will dramatically increase the performance.

Answer (score 1):

actually, all you can do is to add a covering index for the query, that is you need to add the composite index (Skill_Id, User_Id, Matching), and change your WHERE condition to 'Skill_Id IN (3, 5, 18)'.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that this data will grow to 50 millions in the upcoming months AND you are finished with index optimization, I would suggest partitioning for this table.

You may look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html

Quoting from the link

> Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data
>   satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more
>   partitions, which automatically excluding any remaining partitions
>   from the search.

Comment: In my case that`s not gonna work because I don't know which Skills will be selected by the user. If they select skills which belong to different partition my performance gets even worse!

Comment: No it does not. Please read about pruning here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html

Comment: okay I created a new table with partitions and copies all my data into it. I choose paritioning by range for Skill_ID for every 10 Skills 
see above for the exact command!

Comment: can you share your query times?

Comment: more than 2 seconds for five skills from different partition tables in phpmyadmin (in my web app its even worse)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very powerful but not-so-well-known trick. Try this to ensure that the Skill_ID index is used:

```
SELECT User_ID,COUNT(Matching),SUM(Matching)
FROM Matching
inner join (           select 3 as sid
             union all select 5 as sid
             union all select 18 as sid
           ) skills
on skills.sid = Matching.Skill_ID
GROUP BY User_ID
ORDER BY SUM(Matching) DESC
```